# Using ropemacs for autocompletion with python.el in Emacs

Tags: python, emacs, autocomplete, rope, ropemacs

How do I set up auto-complete to use ropemacs with `python.el` in Emacs 24?

I have the following in my `.emacs` file

```
; Auto-complete:
; --------------------------
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete/auto-complete-1.3.1")
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete/auto-complete-1.3.1/dict")
(ac-config-default)

; Auto-complete rope integration:
; --------------------------
(ac-ropemacs-initialize)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
    (add-to-list 'ac-sources 'ac-source-ropemacs)))
```

but this does not seem to be enough to get autocompletions of Python methods, class members, etc. (on the auto-complete tooltip).

e.g.

```
my_text = "hello world"
my_text.
```

does not show any possible autocompletions for the String class.

With the above config, auto-complete itself works well for generic auto-completions (and for directories).

Answer (score 6):

If I may suggest, try [emacs-jedi](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-jedi) if you just want auto completion, and documentation help.

It is <strike>relatively new and in early development stage</strike> matured and reliable enough to work with, way better than the rope route.

Comment: Thanks! Why is it a better route than rope? What are the differences?

Comment: @user273158 two reasons, 1) Its specifically written for auto-completion support for python, a wrapper to jedi (https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi). 2) the author of the package is super active.

Comment: I fully agree; I was trying ropemacs after hours of setting up, and it was awfully slow, so after seeing this I tried emacs-jedi and everything is just pure awesome now.

Comment: agreed. never could get ropemacs set up.  I tried for an entire 8 hour workday.  Sorry ropemacs.